# How to switch to GPU AMD m5 r330

Tags: graphics

I have integrated graphic and AMD m5 r330.

How to switch to AMD m5 r330?

In hardware information I can see that it is available:

Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD®/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]

How to select and use Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD®/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try running "export $DRI_PRIME=1" in terminal and see if this enables your AMD card? (this is temporary and is removed after restart) If it works, we can make it permanent over-all or on a per-app-basis.

Comment: After this command it says: bash: export: `=1': not a valid identifier

Comment: My bad, remove the $ sign from the command: "export DRI_PRIME=1"

Comment: After you told me about DRI_PRIME=1 I googled about it.

I executed DRI_PRIME=1 in terminal, after this I put this in /etc/enviroment and reboot.

After this I checked what GPU this laptop is using.

Checked this way:

1. Installed mesa-utils "sudo apt install mesa-utils"
2. Checked with command "glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
"

Output say: OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD HAINAN (DRM 2.50.0, 5.11.0-44-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)

It looks ok now, I think.

Thanks a lot Vlad!